# Error in webform submit

Tags: webforms

I just created a web form containing questions and answers for my website; when I click on the "Submit" button, the following error appears:

> The requested page "/node/12/done?sid=20" could not be found

The error occurs is followed by this one, when I try to go to results-submissions-view, or delete submitted data.

> The requested page "/node/12/submission/20?render=overlay" could not be found

I checked the permissions, and the webform settings, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Do you have Clean URL's enabled?  Also, what version of Drupal and Webform are you using?

Comment: I have drupal 7 , and Webform version 7.x-3.18 . Where can I enable Clean Url ?

Comment: Yes I have Clean Url's enabled just found it .